# Create a custom WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-custom-view

I have a lot of WebView in different parts of the program, but these WebViews does not differ each other that is why I want to create a custom WebView with necessary settings. At the current moment, WebView doesn't show, but no errors. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    MyWebView mMyWebView;

    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

     public MyWebView initView(Context context){
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         MyWebView view = (MyWebView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_webview, this);
         view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) ;
         view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
         view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
         view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        return view;
    }
}
```

custom_webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/custom_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  MyWebView mWebView;

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = new MyWebView(MainActivity.this);
    mWebView = mWebView.initView(MainActivity.this);
    mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

  }
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
  }

}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
 <com.mypack.webview.MyWebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_URL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: you say layout_below="@id/start_URL", maybe this one is height match_parent?

Comment: I think no, I have button in MainActivity     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="START"
        android:id="@+id/start_URL"/>

Comment: can you try removing the layout_below attribute, what happens then?

Comment: When I put the settings in MainActivity everything OK. I think a problem connected with inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably rewrite your "MyWebView" class. Your method "initView" generates a new MyWebView object everytime but it is never connected to your MainActivity. This could be why you don't see it.

Maybe try something like (untested)

```
    public class MyWebView extends WebView {

        public MyWebView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            initView(context);
        }

        public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initView(context);

        }

        private void initView(Context context){
             // i am not sure with these inflater lines
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             // you should not use a new instance of MyWebView here             
             // MyWebView view = (MyWebView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_webview, this);
             this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) ;
             this.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
             this.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
             this.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        }
    }
```

And call it with

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      MyWebView mWebView;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

      }
      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
      }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works when I use the line: mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view), but with the line:   mWebView = new MyWebView(MainActivity.this) doesn't work!

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance, i will update the code again soon