# Android development: Pdf already generated from html string. Add text to the bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf-generation, pdf-conversion

I have developed a programm that takes an html code and produce a pdf. 
I used the below code to convert the html string to pdf:

https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java

The number of pages of pdf that the programm produce is not fixed.
My question is how could I add at the end of every pdf page a text?

I am looking 5 days for this but I have not find something. I could also listen
to solutions completely different from my approach i.e to first generate the pdf.
I have seen these :

[Creating multiple pages of PDF using android.graphics.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158792/creating-multiple-pages-of-pdf-using-android-graphics-pdf)

[PDF multipage not create in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349397/pdf-multipage-not-create-in-android/36349822#36349822)

[Create a custom WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483342/create-a-custom-webview)

[How to divide the webview content in multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718829/how-to-divide-the-webview-content-in-multiple-pages)

[Create a PDF from Webview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376613/create-a-pdf-from-webview-on-android/49891294#49891294)

[Android - Drawing to a PDF canvas from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828329/android-drawing-to-a-pdf-canvas-from-webview)